# Can I make a hole-punch using normal PHP script on apache server?

Tags: php, hole-punching

There's a concept, maybe a hack, that I've been troubling myself about a long time. What I thought is that essentially, **TCP connection socket is a variable**. It contains some information about your target, which is represented by some specific bytes in your program's memory. And **bytes can be sent to other computers over the internet**.

That concept should allow for a public server to establish direct connection between two private (firewalled or behind router) computers. After googling for a while, I found that this concept indeed exists and is called [Hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_%28networking%29).

It's really different from proxy. Have a look - this is typical proxy/relay connection:

[image: image description]

The data flows through public server. The green circles represent the socket connections between devices, the blue line is the flow of data.

Now what it the server sends socket A to device B and vice versa?

[image: image description]

Suddenly, both devices have each other's "address" and can send any information to each other:

[image: image description]

My question is: Does PHP script allow to get the information needed to share that socket info? How to prevent the socket from being terminated after 30 second PHP time limit?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit confusing to me. You've neglected to mention any details about the clients in the scheme, and the purpose of establishing a connection between them. If you're thinking about this in terms of trying to establish a direct connection between two HTTP clients, then what you're proposing is impossible, since the client software has to be specifically crafted to facilitate this. Moreover, a HTTP client can't act as a server.

I disagree that it's useful to think of a network connection as a variable, or even a state structure. While it's true to a certain extent, the full state of a network connection is typically held in many different places:

- Application state - the two endpoints will typically contain a high-level state about the network connection, such as the Layer 7 protocol being used and further details of that protocol.
- Kernel state - The network state of your OS will contain structures that holds certain low-level details of your connection, such as the TCP state, MTU, and many other things. Again, this will be true for both hosts.
- NAT state table - Here's the tricky one, when it comes to hole punching. In addition to the state of the two communicating hosts, the NAT routers on either end contains state tables that lists the established connections of the hosts being served by each respective NAT router. When a packet arrives on the internet, this table is used to figure out where to send the packet on the internal network.

Hole punching is mostly about tricking the NAT routers to set up the correct entries in their state tables. The exact way of doing this depends on the Layer 4 protocol in use. The schematics in your question shows the typical flow of UDP hole punching, which requires a publicly reachable server. In the case of TCP, which might be what your actually interested in, a server is not necessarily required to start with.

Comment: Yes, the whole PHP thing is there because I don't want to pay for the server and PHP hostings are free. Otherwise I could just run a proxy written in Node.js, C++ or something else. But I can't imagine how to perform hole-punching without the rendevous server. Do you have any details?

Comment: Speaking specifically of TCP, The server might be needed to facilitate the sending of the addresses to the clients, since they both will need to know each others address. Once the hosts are known by both clients it comes down to predicting the ports used by the NAT's and attempting to establish the connection in both directions, after which one of the hosts can close the connection and open a listening socket. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching